# Error message in terminal

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, 20.04

I am new to linux and this error occurs whenever I run `sudo apt update`. I have no idea how to fix this. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your screenshot, or else clarify your question. That cannot be the output you get after running the `sudo apt update` command.

Comment: @vanadium updated.

Comment: It looks like you have messed around with Python installations and broken `apt`'s `python`.